# Problems with unwanted Byte Order Mark in email html

Tags: html, email, byte-order-mark

I design emails for an advertising network. I have found out that the network platform is re-encoding my html files with a Byte Order Mark when I upload them. Therefore, when they are downloaded from the network the BOM appears to break the responsive layout code in the design.

The dev team of the network platform says that they cannot change this process. However, I need to ensure that the email designs that are being downloaded from the network work exactly as designed.

Ideally, I need them to work immediately (rather than having to inform those downloading to re-save without the BOM).

Is there a way to write HTML code so that it will still function with a BOM? Or is this not possible?

This topic is beyond my level of coding knowledge as I only design email creative so please let me know if you need me to explain or clarify. All help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

Thanks for your reply @Dai - here's how the email appears on mobile in the version with BOM, and the version without BOM - as you can see the version with BOM does not display responsively as intended on mobile.

[Top of email without BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpGEa.jpg)

[Top of email with BOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTGlk.png)

(Seems that I can't post more examples due to my reputation being too low!)

As far as I can work out the BOM is somewhere in the first line of code (the DOCTYPE) - because I can just replace the first line from the 'with BOM' code with that of the 'without BOM' code and everything works as expected.

Would it help if I pasted the code here? Would you need the whole html for both to help here? Or just a portion? Many thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Assuming the BOM appears as the first character in the HTML message body then all standards-compliant email readers (even Outlook) will treat it as whitespace when generating the HTML DOM. Are you experiencing other problems, such as the BOM appearing in the middle of HTML content because of a bug in a templating system?

Comment: @Dai                       Any thoughts on my update? Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything further...

Comment: Are you able to get a raw dump of the emails as-received? (i.e. that preserves the raw bytes of the multipart email?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - I have versions of the original html code (without BOM), the html file with the unwanted BOM, and I also have both of these sent from an email send platform to an email account. Could you please explain - in layman's terms as my knowledge of this area is limited - what you would need here?

Comment: @Dai - any further help on this would be appreciated...